# What is the difference between MySQL's create index and alter add index?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table "data" with column id(varchar), text(varchar), date(date). Creating index on mysql, I use heidiSQL.

When I right click on the column and select create new index (key), the code shows it's using `alter table data add index 'index1' ('id,date(10)')`

What is the difference between this and `create index index1 on data ('id,date(10)')`

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The implementation is the same on the server-side.

The only difference is that with CREATE INDEX syntax, you *must* specify a name for the index.

Whereas with ALTER TABLE, you *may* specify a name for the index, but you don't have to.

If you don't specify a name, the server generates a default name, as the name of the first column in the index, with a number suffix if necessary.

Comment: also `CREATE INDEX syntax` is more efficient for big (couple M records)  tables

Comment: @VladimirCh, Do you have evidence for this that you have measured? I believe both statements do exactly the same work, so there should be no difference regardless of the size of the table.

Comment: i tested on 10+ M records, and on `Alter Table....` query was freezed, but `create index...`  request executed successsfuly after some time ofcause, but its worked ok. And it was only one time execution, so i have not evidence.  Exec on  MYSQL 5.6 - Percona

Comment: I would recommend you try to repeat the test. It's possible the ALTER TABLE was waiting for access to the table. If any other session has a transaction holding a metadata lock on the table, then neither ALTER TABLE nor CREATE INDEX can start.

Comment: Or the first test spend extra time loading the data; the second test found all the data cached in RAM.

Comment: CREATE INDEX is mapped to an ALTER TABLE statement to create indexes.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html