# How to create a new index on existing table

Tags: sql, indexing

I have a table in SQL. I would like to add the Age column as a new index to the table.

Table Name: Person
ID field is primary key

| ID | Age | Name | Mobile |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 22 | Alex | 90xxxx |
| 2 | 24 | Bob | 90xxxx |
| 3 | 25 | Cat | 90xxxx |
| 4 | 23 | Mat | 90xxxx |
| 5 | 24 | Bat | 90xxxx |
| 6 | 22 | Rat | 90xxxx |

Option #01:
create index age_index on Person(Age);

Option #02:
alter table Person add index age_index (Age);

Trying to find out the pros and cons of each approach

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only **one** tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: In all relational databases an index is created using the `CREATE INDEX` comand.

Comment: Don't store age. People become older every year, and your data will soon be out-of-date. Store date/year of birth instead.

Comment: I don't recognize the Option 2 syntax, but if it is supported by the dbms you're using, I assume it doesn't matter. However, I'd still use Option 1, since it's the commonly used syntax.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between MySQL's create index and alter add index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17113149/what-is-the-difference-between-mysqls-create-index-and-alter-add-index)