# I am not able to get the indexes in mysql while importing the csv file into mysql

Tags: mysql, mongodb, indexing, mysql-workbench

I have exported the data from MongoDB, and I am importing that csv files into MySQL. I have some indexes in the MongoDB while importing those files to MySQL I am not able to get indexes in MySQL.

Could anyone please help me out. I need those indexes in MySQL. What I need to do?

step 1: I have created the collections MongoDB and in that I have created some indexes on that and         exported into a csv file.
step 2: I have imported that csv files to MySQL.

now I am getting all data but not the indexes, what I need to do to get those indexes on MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can add indexes with [`CREATE INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html) or [`ALTER TABLE...ADD INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html).

You can do this either before or after you load CSV data.

The indexes you need in each SQL table might be different from the indexes you defined in your MongoDB database. In fact, probably so.

Indexes are needed to support specific SQL queries. You can't choose the right indexes until you know which SQL queries your application needs to be optimized.

You might like my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really), or [the video recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU). The presentation is from 2012 but the concepts are pretty evergreen.

Comment: What's the difference between CREATE INDEX and ALTER TABLE...ADD INDEX? See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17113555/20860

Comment: @Karwi , what if I don't know the which indexes are available on that collection, but i need all the Indexes on MySQL.

Comment: You should analyze your SQL queries to decide what indexes to create. It doesn't matter what indexes were present in the MongoDB collection, because your MongoDB queries are bound to be different from your SQL queries and therefore the indexes you need will be different.

Comment: I totally agree with @BillKarwin here (as usual). If all that you have done to move between MongoDB and MySQL is to directly copy your data and queries, then you are using one (or both!) systems improperly. If you aren't using the tools properly then you probably won't be successful with them. Similarly if the only reason/motivation that you have to migrate between databases is because you aren't having success with the first one then you're probably setting yourself up for failure with the second one too.